# Error premature end of file pops up when accessing a URL

Tags: apache-flex, coldfusion, solaris

I am using Coldfsuion 8.0.1 and Solaris 10 and when i try to run this URL, http://IPADDRESS/flex2gateway/http
I am receiving an error message "Premature end of file". Please help me out if i am missing any installation/fix.

And when i hit the same URL from browser it shows:

```
<amfx ver="3">
−
<body targetURI="/onStatus" responseURI="">
−
<object type="flex.messaging.messages.ErrorMessage">
−
<traits>
<string>headers</string>
<string>rootCause</string>
<string>body</string>
<string>correlationId</string>
<string>faultDetail</string>
<string>faultString</string>
<string>clientId</string>
<string>timeToLive</string>
<string>destination</string>
<string>timestamp</string>
<string>extendedData</string>
<string>faultCode</string>
<string>messageId</string>
</traits>
−
<object>
<traits/>
</object>
<null/>
<null/>
<null/>
<null/>
<string>Premature end of file.</string>
<null/>
<double>0.0</double>.........
```

Error details(Server side):

```
[Flex] Premature end of file.
flex.messaging.MessageException: Premature end of file.
        at flex.messaging.io.amfx.AmfxMessageDeserializer.fatalError(AmfxMessageDeserializer.java:249)
        at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:395)
        at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:198)
        at flex.messaging.io.amfx.AmfxMessageDeserializer.parse(AmfxMessageDeserializer.java:103)
        at flex.messaging.io.amfx.AmfxMessageDeserializer.readMessage(AmfxMessageDeserializer.java:90)
        at flex.messaging.endpoints.amf.SerializationFilter.invoke(SerializationFilter.java:113)
```

Comment: What happens when you hit http://IPADDRESS/flex2gateway/http in a web browser?

Comment: Pls check the question now... i added the error details when i hit the url from browser.

Answer (score 1):

Is the response xml dynamically generated?

It seems like the xml file is not validly formatted.  If it's dynamically generated, the app creating it could be bombing out, thus the file is incomplete.